# Python/Pandas DataFrame.Drop can't recognize column name in Chinese Characters

Tags: python

Here is the Jupyter script. Any suggestion why the "Does NOT work" in the following?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('hw1.csv', encoding='utf-8', skipinitialspace=True )
df.drop(['序号'], axis=1, inplace=True) # <= Works
#df.drop(['年度'], axis=1, inplace=True) # <= Does NOT work
df
```

----- hw1.csv file -----
序号,﻿年度,﻿直接排放,﻿间接排放,﻿直接排放间接排放,﻿一般烟煤,﻿汽油,﻿柴油,﻿液化石油气,﻿炼厂干气,﻿天然气
1,2016,4647.09,4843.06,9490.15,2004.98,,136.08,13.9,,45.1816
2,2016,2496.72,3668.16,6164.879999999999,1368.83,,,28.02,,10.593
3,2016,10729.74,4042.2,14771.94,6681.8,,,20.6,,
4,2016,231163.34,206918.68,438082.02,52330.48,,13758.75,997.81,,4690.22
5,2016,7373.27,4994.84,12368.11,3566.25,,,123.6,,60.9229
6,2016,62619.53,3324.15,65943.68,,,,,,2896.1175

Answer (score 3):

All of your column titles, except the first one, start with an invisible Byte-Order Marker (BOM), `'\ufeff`. Remove it before attempting any column-related operation:

```
'年度' in df.columns
# False
df.columns = [s.replace(u'\ufeff', '') for s in df.columns]
'年度' in df.columns
# True
```